# Iterating over JSON object in jquery

Tags: jquery, each

I have a json object as

```
[
{"DisplayName":"Answer Number 1","Value":"Answer1","Option":"True"},
{"DisplayName":"Answer Number 1","Value":"Answer1","Option":"False"},
{"DisplayName":"Answer Number 2","Value":"Answer2","Option":"True"},
{"DisplayName":"Answer Number 2","Value":"Answer2","Option":"False"}
]
```

What I need is to create  2 drop downs from this object as

Answer Number 1 -> True/False

Answer Number 2 -> True/False

dropdown part I'll do my self.. I m just confused on how to iterate over this object.
Can any1 please lead me to some example?

Comment: have you missed a comma after the second element?

Comment: Are you unable to change the structure of the JSON? That seems like an awful way to represent the information you want.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

your json objects `jsonObject` are stored in an array. Do :

```
$.each(jsonArray, function(index,jsonObject){
    $.each(jsonObject, function(key,val){
        console.log("key : "+key+" ; value : "+val);
    });
});
```

it will gives you

```
key : DisplayName ; value : Answer Number 1
key : Value ; value : Answer 1
key : Option ; value : true
```

Anyway, Anthony is right. Your structure will be difficult to manipulate

Comment: Thx alot this one helped

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON isn't valid. 
What about this :

```
var json = '[
    {"DisplayName":"Answer Number 1","Value":"Answer1","Option":"True"},
    {"DisplayName":"Answer Number 1","Value":"Answer1","Option":"False"},
    {"DisplayName":"Answer Number 2","Value":"Answer2","Option":"True"},
    {"DisplayName":"Answer Number 2","Value":"Answer2","Option":"False"}
]';
var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(json); //Only if not already an object
$.each(jsonObject, function (i, obj) {
    alert(obj.DisplayName);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXMFx/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each)

```
$.each( yourArrayOfObjects, function( index, object ){
  // do your magic here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = [{
    "DisplayName": "Answer Number 1",
        "Value": "Answer1",
        "Option": "True"
}, {
    "DisplayName": "Answer Number 1",
        "Value": "Answer1",
        "Option": "False"
}, {
    "DisplayName": "Answer Number 2",
        "Value": "Answer2",
        "Option": "True"
}, {
    "DisplayName": "Answer Number 2",
        "Value": "Answer2",
        "Option": "False"
}];
```

To iterate

```
    for (i in json) {
//json[i] is your current object inside the array, {"DisplayName":"Answer Number 1","Value":"Answer1","Option":"True"}
        for (key in json[i]) {
// keys are DisplayName,  Value, Option
            alert(key);
            alert(json[i][key]); // instead of writing object.key you can also write object[key]
        }
    }
```